# count-by-count matrix. How to make loop structure

Tags: java

I need to create a count-by-count matrix with asterisks in the interior and percent signs around the perimeter. The user is asked to input a number and the number of asterisks, percent signs, and rows depend on the user input.

Example: if the user input is 5 the output will look like this...

```
%%%%%
%***%
%***%
%***%
%%%%%
```

I am trying to use a for loop and I have it programmed so that it will print out 5 asterisks wide and 5 tall, thus making a little square, but I don't know how to get every other row printing out as percent signs.

A somewhat similar code that I have already done is under 7c. Will it be similar? I don't know how to border it with percent signs.

Here is my code so far. I haven't done anything yet for 7d because I have no clue where to start. I know that I will do a loop, but I'm not sure how I will start it. I have put my code in so you can see my variables and other necessary info. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   System.out.println("************** Question 1 *************************\n");
   System.out.println("*\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 2 *************************\n");
   char perc = '%';
   char ast = '*';
   System.out.println(ast+"\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 3 *************************\n");
   for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
   {
      System.out.print(ast);
   }
   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("************** Question 4 *************************");
   System.out.println();
   for (int i =0; i<=9; i++)
   {
      System.out.println(ast);
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("***************************************************");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("************** Question 5 *************************");
   Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter a positive number :");
   int count = keyboardInput.nextInt();
   for (int i=0; i<=count;i++)
   {
      System.out.print(ast);
   }
   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 6 *************************\n");
   for (int i=1;i<=count;i++)
   {
      System.out.print(ast);
      if (i%5==0)
      {
         System.out.println();
      }
   }   
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7a ************************\n");  
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7b ************************\n");
   for (int h=0;h<count;h++)
   {
      for (int w=0;w<count;w++)
      {
         System.out.print(ast);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
   System.out.println(); 
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7c ************************\n");
   for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
   {
      String x;
      if(i%2==0)
      x="*";
      else
      x="%";
      for(int w=0;w<count;w++)
         {
            System.out.print(x);
         }
      System.out.println();
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");
   System.out.println("************** Question 7d ************************\n");
   System.out.println("***************************************************\n");   
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code sample is a little messy. We don't really need to see questions 1 through 6, or how you get input from the user. We only need to see your attempts at solving the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *special-case* printing the first and last row, and printing the first and last character in each row. The algorithm would be:

1. You print one row of `count` percents.
2. You print `count-2` "mixed" rows. (`count-2` to account for the first and last row.)
3. You print the final row of percents.

To print a "mixed" row, your approach will be similar:

1. Print one percent.
2. Print `count-2` asterisks. (`count-2` see above)
3. Print the final percent.

It would be a good idea to use helper functions like `printFullRow()` and `printMixedRow()`. (Which is probably where the assignment was supposed to lead you.) It would also be a good idea to use more helper functions in general.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

```
for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
   {
    if(i>0 && i<count-1)
      System.out.print(ast);
    else
      System.out.print(perc);
   }
```